# Set IE to run as administrator for restricted users?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, administrator, runas

I have locked down a user with windows steady state, but I have put the user folder onto a different partition so that no data from firefox, thunderbird,etc is lost when the user logs off or restarts which is caused by steady state.

I want the restricted user to be able to open Internet Explorer as an administrator, I have been able to do this with the code below but it asks for a password every time the user logs on and not just the first time because windows steady state restores back to how it was.

```
%windir%\system32\runas.exe /user:localhost\administrator /savecred "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe http://google.co.uk"
```

I've read theres no way to add password to this code but I did find a work around when I last did this but can't remember how, any ideas?

Comment: If you're running IE as admin then the user is not restricted.  They can run arbitrary programs through the file dialogs.

Comment: FWIW, running IE in a different user-account than the current login user is not a supported configuration for IE, and bugs do exist.